# html layout gets messed up on zoom

Tags: html, css

I've am currently customizing a theme for an e-commerce website and it works great on all browsers. But when zoomed in (25% to 90%) or zoomed out (only at 150%) my category list on the right side of the page seems to get indented in. I this this is most likely a CSS issue and I tried fixing this on my own, but no good.

You can see it here: http://www.autumnmeadow.com/jar-candles

The code should be able to be seen on the developer tools for whichever browser you are using.  There does not seem to be any issue on IE9 but it does not work correctly on Chrome or FireFox.

Comment: all sites will 'break' at some zoom level, is it really an issue?

Comment: Zoom is an imperfect feature and is implemented differently from browser to browser. Making your site work flawlessly on all at all zoom levels is a waste of time.

Comment: You might consider switching to a platform that handles responsive layout. Here is a good roundup from 2011. I'm sure you can find better options now if you keep searching. http://speckyboy.com/2011/10/24/25-jquery-plugins-to-help-with-responsive-layouts/

Comment: The site isn't responsive in the slightest, what were you hoping would happen?  The browser would magically reformat the page for you?

Answer (score 0):

Try making the width and height in % and not in px. lets say if you want it to fill the half of the screen, make it 50%.

```
<div width="50%" height="100%"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use css `transform: scale(...)` based on what the zoom level is and scale the size up/down, therefore negating the zoom level.

Github project for detecting zoom levels, [here](https://github.com/tombigel/detect-zoom)